# Possible to Export KineticJS Complete Layer

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Does anybody know if there is a way to 'export' an entire KineticJS layer (or group) and not just the part that is in the visible canvas?

I have a simple 'image editor' that allows the user to scale the image in the canvas, the image can deliberately be scaled larger than the visible canvas stage area allowing the user to pan the image sections into view. The problem is that when they come to export the image (currently using the toDataURL) only the section of the image in the visible canvas stage is saved, the rest of the image is discarded!

I effectively want to save the whole layer, not just what is rendered in the visible canvas stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You need a temporary workaround.

I assume you have a function or something that does .toDataURL().

Right before you do toDataURL(), change the stage size or scale, then save, then change back.

Example:

```
 function save(){
     stage.setScale(newX,newY); //rescale to new values
     stage.setWidth(newWidth);
     stage.setHeight(newHeight);

     stage.toDataURL();   // <----- save

     stage.setScale(oldX,oldY); //rescale to old values
     stage.setWidth(oldWidth);
     stage.setHeight(oldHeight);
 }
```

This will resize or rescale your stage and then put it back the way it was.

Comment: You got the idea. You need to run `stage.draw()` to get the image properly and don't need to set width/height back and forth.